# Why are there so many CSS properties which are essentially the same?

Tags: naming, css, standards

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting#answer-4407335) really made me wonder.

I've written CSS before and (usually) I don't really bother to support browsers other than recent firefox and chrome, but in researching I've noticed that, for the exact same CSS property, there are usually at least three different forms which behave identically, and can have the same values, but which all simply have different prefixes for the specific library that implements them.

Here, for example:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

With the sole exception of the first one, these only differ by prefix. Why don't maintainers simply change the lexer rule which matches the string "-moz-user-select" to also match "user-select"? Sure, there's the possibility that the author of the original CSS wanted different behavior for Firefox v. other browsers, so "user-select" won't be the same as "-moz-user-select", but the risk of that weird corner case is far outweighed by the advantage, and there are other, arguably better ways to accomplish the browser-specific goal.

If this is already occurring, why do people still use all of these? If they stopped:

- there would be fewer bits clogging the metaphorical pipes of the internet (network latency would go way down, plus individual pages would load faster), and
- people using ancient browsers would be given the impetus they need to update (which they should do for security reasons, anyway)

### TL;DR

What would the disadvantage be of everyone using the same naming convention? Why haven't things normalized by now?

Comment: There are no attributes in CSS. (There are attribute selectors, but that’s a different issue.) What you are trying to ask is just “why are there vendor-prefixed versions for CSS properties?” This is a broad question and partly a matter of opinions. In particular, `user-select` was once part of a *working draft*, now withdrawn, so what you are seeing is just browser-specific properties with no definitions beyond those that each vendor might provide (in some format, usually in informal and inexact language).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks. I did mean property. I knew there was something off in there... Fixed it, anyway.

Comment: If you are worrying about bandwidth, then consider that text uses a lot less bandwidth compared with video, audio or pictures. Also with compression, as there is a lot of similarity in all 6 cases it will use even less, so make sure your server supports compression (and caching).

Comment: @richard Good points. Although one of the issues is that, if a website whose traffic routes through the same node as mine doesn't use compression and tries for cross-browser compatibility by offloading to a comparatively enormous library that touts itself as abstracting away browser-specific issues, traffic to their site strangles traffic to mine.

Comment: Where as if you sit next to a site that stream video, and uses way way way way way more bandwidth, then they may put in a network upgrade, and your site will get faster. (I did not, and can not, put in enough “ways” to illustrate how much bandwidth video uses compared to text.)

Comment: Some browser makers are moving away from prefixes. http://www.chromium.org/blink#vendor-prefixes

Comment: @richard True... Thank you, Youtube and Netflix. May your video codecs be always efficiently compressing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of these are due to vendor prefixes.

A new standard that has not been finalized may get implemented in a browser, but since it has not been finalized, the browser vendor (creator) will not want to use the "official" correct attribute, but they still want to support the feature.

So they add a prefix - `-webkit-*`, `-moz-*`, `-khtml-` and `-ms-*` are specific to the different browsers/rendering engines.

And as a developer, while browsers gain support but don't yet use the "official" name, you may want to support the feature - so you add the vendor prefixes and the official one for future proofing.

Sometimes a feature changes name during the standardization process, so you end up with a vendor prefix using a different name, or having two different names for the same feature (normally in different browser versions of the same rendering engine).

---

> Why haven't things normalized by now?

New standards are being worked on and getting finalized **all the time**. Different vendors have different priorities on which vendors they want to support. So - a moving target + different priorities, gives you... vendor prefixes and no single standard name at one point in time.

Comment: I suppose the question that leaves me with then is "why is there pressure on the library authors to prematurely release features which haven't been standardized yet, thereby cluttering the namespace?"

Comment: @ParthianShot - what library authors? Browser creators want to support the latest and greatest (thought their definitions of greatest vary).

Comment: The browser authors writing whatever library handles CSS interpretation. It seems shortsighted to add something to the namespace to fix a lack of support that will be resolved in far less time than that particular browser version will be in circulation.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why the browser authors don't use the standard name before the standard is finished, listing support for the feature in that browser version as "provisional" or "partial" and then updating the code (if it needs updating) in future versions. That's already done for some standardized properties, and it seems to work okay.

Comment: The features have to be tested, to do that they have to be implemented. It is hard to design on paper and get it correct first time, I have never seen it done.

Comment: They use there own name, because the standard is not finalised, the standard can change. By using the standards name incorrectly or before finalisation, they will be out of compliance.

Comment: Weird. Okay, so, to make sure I'm getting this right... If a browser just flat-out doesn't support a feature, it can say it complies to the standard the defines that feature in that attempting to use that feature is an all-or-nothing proposition (either it works or nothing happens), but defining a feature of the same name differently means they can't legally claim compliance to the standard in that product version? How does this differ from when a browser partially implements the functionality outlined in the standard? In practical terms isn't it the same difference? Both are partway wrong.

Comment: This is genuine curiosity, by the way. I know that's hard to express over the internet.

Comment: To add to the "why standards not normalized" portion (and this is outside my bailiwick but something I understand from close friends who do a ton of CSS), there are companies like MS who intentionally refuse to obey standards as part of a business strategy to damage the competition's ability to perform in the marketplace.  This is very bad for standards and efficiency and extremely annoying for programmers, but it's a fact of life.  So CSS has to cater to what browsers will do rather than the other way around.  There are a ton of bizarre things you must do to get a page to show properly in IE.

Comment: @TrixieWolf Yeah, I don't really understand that marketing strategy. Maybe it's just the 20/20 hindsight, but it seems pretty obvious that ignoring standards will make your browser objectively worse at rendering everyone's pages, because no one outside industry will want to go to that level of coding effort for such little gain, and as a result end users won't buy the (intentionally sub-par) product.

Comment: I understand the reasons, but I don't think they're valid.   I know things like `flex` have changed, but I fail to see how having 5+ separate prefixes for a preliminary standard where those prefixed meanings may change anyway is a good idea.  They're normally all the same preliminary standard anyway, why not just have a name starting with a dash and no browser name that all browsers can implement?  They should search standard->browser->unnamed so that you can override the unnamed for specific browsers if something is different, but I can't think of an example off the top of my head.

Comment: @ParthianShot  It's not a good marketing strategy.  It is probably the main reason for MS losing ground in browser share, a minor reason for MS losing ground in other markets, and the primary reason web developers hate MS.  It is probably a factor behind Ballmer's resignation.  As a strategy, it only works for as long as you maintain a strong competitive edge over every other company.  The moment that edge drops, it works heavily against you.  It's also (arguably) unethical and stupid.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Part of the point is that the prefixed ones don't _have to_ change, because they're vendor-specific.

Comment: @Izkata And his point is that, under the system he's proposing, they still wouldn't have to change. The `-` prefix would denote an experimental implementation, while `-vendor-` would be the vendor-specific experimental implementation, if that implementation differed from the other experimental ones. And _that_ wouldn't have to change, either.

Comment: @ParthianShot [Yeah, this comic exists for a reason](http://xkcd.com/927/)...

Comment: @Izkata True...